# Ajax now functioning right value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to develop a hotel booking website.. It goes like in 1st page you have to choose a destination, check in date and check out date with the number of people.
In the 2nd page, its shows the number of hotels available in that destination, and on selecting the choice of hotel, you are directed to 3rd page where types of rooms of that hotel and price of the room is showing with an option to book.

3rd page also allows you to change the check in and check out dates with the number of peoples to stay.

I have used Ajax to make this changes and give the new price of the room according to the new selected dates:

But This function of mine is not working properly. please help me to solve it

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addR()
{
    var term_name = $('#FromDate').val();       //Storing the value of textbox into a variable
    var ToDate = $('#ToDate').val();        //Storing the value of textbox into a variable
    var SessionID = $('#SessionID').val();      //Storing the value of textbox into a variable
    var HotelID = $('#HotelID').val();      //Storing the value of textbox into a variable
    var Adult = $('#Adult').val();      //Storing the value of textbox into a variable
    var Child = $('#Child').val();      //Storing the value of textbox into a variable
    var ajRoomNo = $('#ajxRoomNo').val();       //Storing the value of textbox into a variable

    if(term_name == '')                     //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('Please Enter Your Check-In Date'); //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#FromDate').addClass('error');                   //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }
        if(ToDate == '')                        //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('Please Enter Your Check-Out Date');    //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#ToDate').addClass('error');                 //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }
    /*IF ROOM NO IS  1*/
    if(Adult >= '4' && ajRoomNo == '1')                     //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('No. of guests exceed room capacity. Please add extra room!');  //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#Adult').addClass('error');                  //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }

    if(Child >= '1' && Adult >= '3' && ajRoomNo == '1')                     //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('No. of guests exceed room capacity. Please add extra room!');  //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#Child').addClass('error');                  //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }

    if(Child >= '2' && Adult >= '2' && ajRoomNo == '1')                     //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('No. of guests exceed room capacity. Please add extra room!');  //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#Child').addClass('error');                  //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }
    if(Child >= '3' && Adult >= '1' && ajRoomNo == '1')                     //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('No. of guests exceed room capacity. Please add extra room!');  //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#Child').addClass('error');                  //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }
    /*IF ROOM NO IS  2*/



    if(Child >= '5' && Adult >= '2' && ajRoomNo == '2')                     //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('No. of guests exceed room capacity. Please add extra room!');  //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#Child').addClass('error');                  //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }

    if(Child >= '4' && Adult >= '3' && ajRoomNo == '2')                     //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('No. of guests exceed room capacity. Please add extra room!');  //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#Child').addClass('error');                  //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }

    if(Child >= '3' && Adult >= '4' && ajRoomNo == '2')                     //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('No. of guests exceed room capacity. Please add extra room!');  //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#Child').addClass('error');                  //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }

    if(Child >= '2' && Adult >= '5' && ajRoomNo == '2')                     //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('No. of guests exceed room capacity. Please add extra room!');  //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#Child').addClass('error');                  //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }

    if(Child >= '1' && Adult >= '6' && ajRoomNo == '2')                     //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('No. of guests exceed room capacity. Please add extra room!');  //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#Child').addClass('error');                  //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }

    if(Child >= '6' && Adult >= '1' && ajRoomNo == '2')                     //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('No. of guests exceed room capacity. Please add extra room!');  //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#Child').addClass('error');                  //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }
    /*IF ROOM NO IS  3*/


    if(Child >= '5' && Adult >= '6' && ajRoomNo == '3')                     //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('No. of guests exceed room capacity. Please add extra room!');  //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#Child').addClass('error');                  //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }


    if(Child >= '4' && Adult >= '6' && ajRoomNo == '3')                     //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('No. of guests exceed room capacity. Please add extra room!');  //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#Child').addClass('error');                  //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }


    if(Child >= '5' && Adult >= '5' && ajRoomNo == '3')                     //Checking for NULL
    {
        $('#propspectDiv').html('No. of guests exceed room capacity. Please add extra room!');  //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
        $('#Child').addClass('error');                  //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
        return;
    }
    else{
        $('#FromDate').removeClass('error');
        $('#propspectDiv').removeClass('error');                                    //Removing the error class from the progress DIV
        $('#propspectDiv').html('Submitting your Request.<img src="<?php print 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/ajax.gif" />'); //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV

        $.ajax({
                url : '<?php print 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/data.php',                  //Declaration of file, in which we will send the data
                data:{
                    //"name" : term_name                //we are passing the name value in URL
                    "FromDate" : term_name,
                    "ToDate" : ToDate,                      //we are passing the name value in URL
                    "SessionID" : SessionID,                        //we are passing the name value in URL
                    "HotelID" : HotelID,                        //we are passing the name value in URL
                    "Adult" : Adult,                        //we are passing the name value in URL
                    "Child" : Child,                        //we are passing the name value in URL
                    "ajxRoomNo" :ajRoomNo                       //we are passing the name value in URL
                },

                success : function(data){
                    window.setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#propspectDiv').html('Your search criteria has been updated'); //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
                        $('#data').css("display","block");  //Changes the style of table from display:none to display:block
                        $('#data').html(data);              //Prints the data into the table
                    }, 2000);
                }
            });
    }
}

</script>
```

and my on spot changing function through submit button is:

```
<!--Start Modify Search-->
    <div>
Modify your Search
                        <div class="con">    

                        <div id="w">
                        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" border="1" width="100%">

                        <input type="hidden" id="HotelID" value="<?php print $ghi;?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="SessionID" value="<?php print $SessionI;?>" />
                        <thead>
                           <tr>
                            <td class="roomvalues">Check-in Date : </td>
                            <td class="roomvalues">Check-out Date : </td>
                            <td class="roomvalues">Room (Select 1-5)</td>
                            <td class="roomvalues">Adult</td>
                             <td class="roomvalues">Children</td>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                         <td><input type="text" name="From-Date" value="<?php if($searchfirstdate!='01/01/1991'){echo '$searchfirstdate';}else{ echo "";}?>" id="FromDate"  class="input1 date-picker required date" style="border:1px #7F9DB9 solid;"/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="ToDate" value="<?php if($searchenddate!='01/01/1970'){echo $searchenddate;}else{ echo "";}?>" id="ToDate" class="input1 date-picker2 required date" style="border:1px #7F9DB9 solid;"/></td>
                                <td>
                                 <!--<select name="ajxRoomNo" id="ajxRoomNo">
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                 </select>-->

                                 <select name="ajxRoomNo" id="ajxRoomNo">
                                    <option value="1" <?php if($RoomNo==1) echo "selected"; ?>>1</option>
                                    <option value="2" <?php if($RoomNo=='2') echo "selected"; ?>>2</option>
                                    <option value="3" <?php if($RoomNo=='3') echo "selected"; ?>>3</option>
                                    <option value="4" <?php if($RoomNo=='4') echo "selected"; ?>>4</option>
                                    <option value="5" <?php if($RoomNo=='5') echo "selected"; ?>>5</option>
                                 </select>


                                 </td>
                                 <td>
                                 <select name="Adult" id="Adult">
                            <option value="1"<?php if($person=='1') echo "selected"; ?>>1</option>
                            <option value="2"<?php if($person=='2') echo "selected"; ?>>2</option>
                            <option value="3"<?php if($person=='3') echo "selected"; ?>>3</option>
                            <option value="4"<?php if($person=='4') echo "selected"; ?>>4</option>
                            <option value="5"<?php if($person=='5') echo "selected"; ?>>5</option>
                            <option value="6"<?php if($person=='6') echo "selected"; ?>>6</option>
                         </select>
                                 </td>
                                 <td>
                                 <select name="Child" id="Child">
                            <option value="0"<?php if($children=='0') echo "selected"; ?>>0</option>
                            <option value="1"<?php if($children=='1') echo "selected"; ?>>1</option>
                            <option value="2"<?php if($children=='2') echo "selected"; ?>>2</option>
                            <option value="3"<?php if($children=='3') echo "selected"; ?>>3</option>
                            <option value="4"<?php if($children=='4') echo "selected"; ?>>4</option>
                            <option value="5"<?php if($children=='5') echo "selected"; ?>>5</option>
                         </select>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5">
                            <input type="button" class="mys" value="Search" onClick="addR()" />
                            </td>
                       </tbody> 
                       </table>
                        <div id="propspectDiv"></div>

                    </div>


                       </div>
    </div>
    <!--End Modify Search-->
```

Comment: Define "not working properly."  What indication do you have that there's a problem?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  Unexpected behavior?  When you debug it, at what point does the expected behavior change?

Comment: It is not fetching rooms anymore when the date is change from here
Just giving the success message

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. I tried to run you code in JSFiddle and the console gave me a few errors. I fixed them for you. There was a problem in Encapsulation of Data URL

Replace the else part in your JS script with this

```
    var inhtml = "Submitting your Request.<img src='http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/ajax.gif' />";
    var urlsend = "<?php print 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/data.php";
    $('#FromDate').removeClass('error');
    $('#propspectDiv').removeClass('error');                                    //Removing the error class from the progress DIV
    $('#propspectDiv').html(inhtml); //Prints the progress text into our Progress DI

    $.ajax({
            url : urlsend,                  //Declaration of file, in which we will send the data
            data:{
                //"name" : term_name                //we are passing the name value in URL
                "FromDate" : term_name,
                "ToDate" : ToDate,                      //we are passing the name value in URL
                "SessionID" : SessionID,                        //we are passing the name value in URL
                "HotelID" : HotelID,                        //we are passing the name value in URL
                "Adult" : Adult,                        //we are passing the name value in URL
                "Child" : Child,                        //we are passing the name value in URL
                "ajxRoomNo" :ajRoomNo                       //we are passing the name value in URL
            },

            success : function(data){
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#propspectDiv').html('Your search criteria has been updated'); //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
                    $('#data').css("display","block");  //Changes the style of table from display:none to display:block
                    $('#data').html(data);              //Prints the data into the table
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
```